# HR width 100% issue

Tags: javascript, html

Could you tell me how to limit content width to the screen boundary? For the following script i always get 2px width wider than screen (allowed space) width.

document.body.scrollWidth is always 2px wider than screen

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {margin: 0; padding: 0}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            alert(document.body.scrollWidth);
            alert(document.getElementById("hrtest").scrollWidth);
            alert(document.getElementById("divtest").scrollWidth);
            alert(screen.width);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="test()">
    <div id="divtest">
        <hr size="2" width="100%" id="hrtest" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
hr {
    border-right : 0;
    border-left: 0;
}
```

Should do it.
You may wish to add important to the style, or iterate through all hr in document and set in-line style.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the problem is the browser is adding a 1 px border to build the hr. Inspecting the hr with chrome shows us the following styles applied by default to all hr's:

```
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 0.5em;
-webkit-margin-after: 0.5em;
-webkit-margin-start: auto;
-webkit-margin-end: auto;
border-style: inset;
border-width: 1px;
```

Disabling the `border-width: 1px;` will give the expected results, but hides the hr. Anyway, removing the hr's width works :P

Comment: Yes this is a problem with the 1px border in Internet Explorer.  1px on each side adds for the 2px discrepancy.  This is a non-issue in browsers that obey the proper box model, e.g. Firefox, etc.

Comment: @user1169578, well, when setting the width to 100% to an hr, it exceeds the page width in Chrome and Firefox as well, not only in IE. As I said in my answer, I tested it in Chrome, and it resulted in an horizontal scroll bar :P

Comment: I got no scroll bar in FF.  I just ran the code and tallied the output:  In FF: body width: 1680
hr width:1680
div width: 1680
screen width: 1680  in IE: body width: 1003
hr width:1001
div width: 1003
screen width: 1680

Comment: Did you know of any other element that behaves like that?

Comment: Yep, my fault, FF works just fine. Chrome doesn't, though.
ED: Mmm, I can't think of any right now, but any element (a simple div for example), with a 100% width and a 1px border would be the same. Anyway, that's not by default, you need to add the 1px border.

Comment: Due to inconsistencies in browsers I wouldn't recommend putting 100% width on hr, given its default behavior.  Various answers all give good ideas on what to do.

Answer (score 1):

> The default user agent stylesheet for the
>
> ---
>
> (Horizontal Line) HTML
>   element is :

```
hr {
  display: block;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0.5em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0.5em;
  -webkit-margin-start: auto;
  -webkit-margin-end: auto;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

*If you want to fix horizontal scroll across the HTML document then follow the solution:*

**Solution#1:**

```
hr{
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Solution#2:**

```
hr{
width: 100%;
border-left: 0px;
border-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the border width to 0 will fix this.

http://jsfiddle.net/chuckplayer/AuC8b/

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0}


   <div id="divtest" width="100%">
        <hr size="2" width="100%" id="hrtest" />
    </div>

  alert(document.body.scrollWidth);
            alert(document.getElementById("hrtest").scrollWidth);
            alert(document.getElementById("divtest").scrollWidth);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the `<hr>` to match the exact width of the `body` then I would recommend hiding the border style of the `<hr>` and using a `background-color` with a `height: 1px`.  You can view the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/helpinspireme/fg6Mp/3/

**CSS**

```
hr{
  border-style: none;
  background: #000;
  height: 1px;}
```

​
**jQuery**

```
var body_width = $('body').width();
var div_width = $('div').width();
var hr_width = $('hr').width();
alert(body_width);
alert(div_width);
alert(hr_width);
```

​
**HTML**

```
<div>
  <hr/>
</div>​
```

Comment: Also note for older browsers you will need to set `font-size: 0` and `line-height: 0` to remove any default height given to the `<hr>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Use a table as follows:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td>
    <!-- your htlm block -->
</td></tr>
<tr><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;" height="50">
</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can play with the height of the row or use border-top, each time you need a hr add this row in your table